# MySql get value of default or min row

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with structure

```
ID|GROUP_ID|DEFAULT|VALUE
13|      10|      0|   20
14|      11|      0|   30
15|      10|      0|   40
16|      10|      1|   50
17|      11|      0|   60
```

I want to get one row for each GROUP_ID by rule:

if GROUP_ID has row with DEFAULT = 1 I have to get this row

if GROUP_ID doesn't have row with DEFAULT = 1 I have to get row with MIN(VALUE)

For above data result should be:

```
16|10|1|50
14|11|0|30
```

How can I do this with MySql?

Comment: Hint: Write a subquery that gets the min value, and left join it with a subquery that gets the default value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this in MySQL.  Here is one method:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.id = (select t2.id
              from t t2
              where t2.group_id = t.group_id
              order by (default = 1) desc, value asc
              limit 1
             );
```

The subquery orders all rows for a given group based on your rules.  The expression `(default = 1) desc`, put the default values first.  In a numeric context, MySQL treats boolean values as numbers, with "1" for true and "0" for false (hence the `desc`).

Comment: For query above i got error

[21000][1242] Subquery returns more than 1 row

Comment: You need `LIMIT 1` in the subquery.